# LEGO Technic Interface A

Tags: technic, software

A few days ago, a friend offered me one set 9750 LEGO Technic Interface A with the Interface Card and Cable (IBM compatible) but without software.

Can someone share the installation software (LEGO Lines, LEGO TC Logo or Logowriter Robotics) or where can I download the original software for IBM PC-DOS??

Comment: The person behind this link says they have software and cables to interface with this device: http://lgauge.com/

Comment: I had already found the site mentioned by jvd. It contains lots of useful information about the Interface A.


What I wanted was to find the original software, especially the LEGO TC Logo for IBM (MS-DOS).

Comment: If you goal is only to be able to use it, it seems faster to hack it using an Arduino and than control it through USB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5PVarmqxaOnVkZ2bGJybVhwSVk/view) to a google drive ZIP file seems to be the ISA card installation documentation and PC-DOS application you are looking for.

More information on using the LEGO Technic Interface A with an Apple II or Commodore 64 can be found [here](http://lukazi.blogspot.com/2014/07/lego-legos-first-programmable-product.html).

Comment: There was at one point also an interface for the ZX Spectrum too although I realise this is not too relevant to the original question however mentioning it as other 8 bit systems were also noted.

Comment: There was an interface for the Sinclair ZX it just wasn't made by the Lego Group. It was made by Datel Electronics Ltd (UK) in 1984 called the [Datel Robotek](http://www.worldofspectrum.org/infoseekid.cgi?id=1000097). A companion book ["Make And Program Your Own Robots" by William Clark, Lionel Bender](http://www.worldofspectrum.org/infoseekid.cgi?id=2000479) was also published.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I see you are completely correct now.

Answer (score 3):

The software for Technic Interface A is said to be the same for the lego DACTA interface (aka 'interface B').

Try this download [link](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=5641cce2a1cc0886&id=5641CCE2A1CC0886%21309) for lego DACTA control Lab

This eurobricks [thread](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/67665-dacta-control-lab-software/) may also be of some use